# chartjs - How to access chart instance in a custom tooltip callback

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**Given:**
In the below example a line chart with a solid line, a dashed line and a custom tooltip was created.

**Question**
How can we access from inside the custom callback if the affected lines are solid or dashed? Basically I want to know from within the custom callback if the attribute "borderDash" in the dataset is existing.

```js
var s1 = {
  label: 'A',
  data: [{
      x: '2020-05-11T04:58:37Z',
      y: 25,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T04:59:17Z',
      y: 27,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T04:59:57Z',
      y: 21,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T05:00:37Z',
      y: 21,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T05:01:17Z',
      y: 21,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T05:01:57Z',
      y: 0.04,
    }
  ],
  borderDash: [10, 5]

};

var s2 = {
  label: 'B',
  data: [{
      x: '2020-05-11T04:58:37Z',
      y: 28,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T04:59:17Z',
      y: 31,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T04:59:57Z',
      y: 27,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T05:00:37Z',
      y: 30,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T05:00:57Z',
      y: 30,
    },
    {
      x: '2020-05-11T05:01:17Z',
      y: 0.033,
    }
  ]
};

var customTooltips = function(tooltip) {
  //** 
  //* QUESTION: How to get info if line is dotted or solid?
  //**

  // Tooltip Element
  var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

  if (!tooltipEl) {
    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
    this._chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
  }

  // Hide if no tooltip
  if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
  }

  // Set caret Position
  tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
  if (tooltip.yAlign) {
    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
  } else {
    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
  }

  function getBody(bodyItem) {
    return bodyItem.lines;
  }

  // Set Text
  if (tooltip.body) {
    var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);

    var innerHtml = '<thead>';

    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
      innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
    });
    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
      var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
      var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
      style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
      style += '; border-width: 2px';
      var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
      innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
    });
    innerHtml += '</tbody>';

    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
  }

  var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
  var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

  // Display, position, and set styles for font
  tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
  tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
  tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize + 'px';
  tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
  tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [s1, s2]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
      mode: 'index',
      position: 'nearest',
      custom: customTooltips
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        distribution: 'series'
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the customTooltips function you can access the datasets by this._data.datasets. Then you can loop trough the datasets to see if borderdash exist. In the example below I used .map to create new array.

```
let data = this._data.datasets
let borderDash = data.map((item,index) => {
    return {
        label:item.label,
        index,
        borderDash: item.borderDash?true:false
    }  
})

console.log(borderDash)
```